# How to pass data between classes? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class which I get email data from the user. It's basicly a textfield so I wont post the textfield code. After I get the email and password data, I check if these data is in my Firestore database. If it is, I want to pass this email data to my other class which I get the other informations about customer.

Here is the code of trying to check if user exists when I click the button.This is my LoginScreen() class' Material Button's onPressed action. I only get the email from the user here and want to pass this email data to my CustomerInfo class if the user already exists in my FirebaseAuth.Also the CustomerScreen class is for the show all customer information on the screen. I will add some code to push the customer information after I successfully get the data form database.

```
try {
                    final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email!, password: password!);
                    if (user != null) {
                      CustomerInfo(email: email);
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => CustomerScreen()));
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
```

Also I have another class which I'm trying to get customers data.

```
 class CustomerInfo {
  String? email;
  String? name;
  String? surname;
  String? avatarLink;
  int? balance;

  CollectionReference customers =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers');

  CustomerInfo({this.email});

  Future getCustomerData() async {
    print("Email: $email");
    await customers.where('email', isEqualTo: email).get().then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((result) {
        name = result['name'];
        surname = result['surname'];
        balance = result['balance'];
        avatarLink = result['image'];
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Also CustomerInfo class:

```
import 'package:banking_app_firebase/constants.dart';
import 'package:banking_app_firebase/networking.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login_screen.dart';

class CustomerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomerScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomerScreenState createState() => _CustomerScreenState();
}

class _CustomerScreenState extends State<CustomerScreen> {
  String? name;
  String? surname;
  int? balance;
  String? image;

  void getData() async {
    CustomerInfo customerInfo = CustomerInfo();
    await customerInfo.getCustomerData();

    name = customerInfo.name;
    print("Name: $name");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Account Summary",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.bell,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/23/04/01/woman-1274056_960_720.jpg"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Deneme",
                style: kInfoTextDecoration,
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Deneme",
                style: kInfoTextDecoration,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I pass the email data to my CustomerInfo class so I can use getCustomerData()? Using CustomerInfo(email:email) did not work.

Comment: You can use FirebaseAuth's instance to get currentUser. Then you can get email from currentUser using `currentUser.getEmail();`

Comment: @KshitijDhakal Hey. I can get the email in my base class. What I want to do is just passing this email data to another class.

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance() returns singleton. So you should be able to use in any class.

Comment: @KshitijDhakal isn't that give me a unnecessary API  call? I just want to simply send already used email data to another class. But I will try this .

Comment: Why are you creating a `CustomerInfo(email: email)' in the first code sample (inside the `try` block? You are not saving the instance to a variable so you are just creating a `CustomerInfo()` and never using it.

Comment: @Hady I mean, ı thought I can pass the email data to CustomerInfo like this.

Comment: @sonelektrikci that doesn't pass the data. Think of the class you created as an `int` or a `double`. Can you do `int.isEven`? That doesn't make any sense as what is the value of the integer? What you do is you create a new variable for example, `int number = 5;` then `number.isEven`. A `static` value would be the same across all instances. For example if you want to make an online user count, that would make sense to be static so that it updates everyone on your app and the user doesn't see two different values and you only have to update once. 1/3

Comment: If you want to have the same class with different values then it wouldn't be static. In your case, the email isn't static so you have to save and pass around the same instance of the `CustomerInfo()` with that `email`. `static` aside, you can look at my answer as I provide some examples. I'm guessing you need the user data in the `CustomScreen()`. If so, then look at the answer I provided. I cannot help anymore than this without a code sample for `CustomScreen()` to know exactly what you are trying to do. Here is a tutorial series which might help you use firebase auth. 2/3

Comment: and firestore: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC 3/3

Comment: I think you have a lack of essential knowledge about creating classes and accessing their members. Every time you call `CustomerInfo()`, you actually acquire a different instance occupying space in your memory. You providing `email` data for a class does not mean that you can access the same data from another without providing any.

Comment: Yeah, I had to create object from that class. @StewieGriffin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.

Is this what you are trying to do? You are passing email correctly. You just need to call `getCustomerData()`

```dart
try {
  final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email!, password: password!);
  if (user != null) {
    var customerInfo = CustomerInfo(email: email);
    await customerInfo.getCustomerData();
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CustomerScreen(customerInfo: customerInfo)));
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Then in CustomerScreen it would look like this

```dart
class CustomerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CustomerInfo customerInfo;
  const CustomerScreen({Key? key, this.customerInfo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomerScreenState createState() => _CustomerScreenState();
}

class _CustomerScreenState extends State<CustomerScreen> {
  String? name;
  String? surname;
  int? balance;
  String? image;

  void getData()  {
   name = widget.customerInfo.name;
   surname = widget.customerInfo.surname;
   balance = widget.customerInfo.balance;
   image = widget.customerInfo.image;
  }
```

But I would recommend you take a look into FutureBuilder.

Comment: Let me tell you what I'm doing. I have 3 classes. LoginScreen,CustomerScreen and CustomerInfo. In login screen, I get the email and password data from user to check if it matches with my Firebase. If it is, I'm trying to pass email data to the CustomerInfo class get this users all information. And after that I will pass name,surname,balance etc info to the CustomerScreen and use it in my design. I added the CustomerScreen class so you can check how the code works.

Comment: Why don't you pass email as a parameter in CustomerScreen instead then? Then in getData(), you can use `widget.email` to get the email.

Comment: When you create a new object it doesn't maintain the state of the old object unless they are singleton. So even though you called `CustomerInfo(email: email)`, when you called `CustomerInfo customerInfo = CustomerInfo();`, it creates new instance. It doesn't returns old instance.

Comment: I did not want to do the networking functions in any of these screens. I wanted to do the networking job in another class. However, I prob will pass the data directly in CustomerScreen

Comment: I just lost myself in the all answers ahaha

Comment: Yeap this code worked. However, this time I'm getting this error: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. @Kshitij Dhakal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236343/discussion-between-kshitij-dhakal-and-sonelektrikci).

Answer (score 1):

this will not work as the email field is not static so you can't use `CustomerInfo.getCustomerData()`. You need to create an instance of custom user and then use the `getCustomerData()` method.

For example: `var data = await CustomerInfo(email: email).getCustomerData();`
or if you are going to use the CustomerInfo()` multiple times you can do the following:

```dart
final CustomerInfo info = CustomerInfo(email: email);

var data = info.getCustomerData();
```

or something similar to that.

If you are trying to display the info inside of the `CustomScreen()` I think it might be easier to just create a `CustomerInfo()` there and get whatever data you need.

All I can do is guess as you haven't provided a sample for `CustomScreen()` or what it is meant to do. If you are trying to the customer data in the `CustomScreen()` then it might be better to use a `FutureBuilder()` to show your user that the data is loading then display it once the future completes rather than just having an async callback before pushing the route making the user think that they didn't click the button.

Comment: An even better option would be to just get the user from `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` and get the email from the currently logged in user instead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preferences. For example, usually, I create a `global.dart`  and store temporary variables there. for example in your global.dart:

```
CustomerInfo selectedUser;
```

then you can set it wherever you want. for example:

```
import './global.dart' as global;

try {
                    final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email!, password: password!);
                    if (user != null) {
                      CustomerInfo(email: email);
                      global.selectedUser = CustomeInfo(SET PARAMETERS);
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => CustomerScreen()));
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
```

the you can use it by calling `global.selectedUser` wherever you want.
Other approach is using `Provider` but it is useful when you want to change the variable in many files.
Also, you can use `firebase` methods for getting active user and his/her info like `getEmail()` but I do not recommend it because of unnecessary API call.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly but I want to send the email data to CustomerInfo class. Not the vice-versa. In this code, you are trying to to get the email from CustomerInfo class,am I right?

Comment: actually, based on my solution you can access user info (customer info) wherever you want. For example if you want to access it in `CustomerInfo class`, first `import './global.dart' as global;` then use it by `global.selectedUser`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the email info from _auth.

```
  try {
final user = await _auth!.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email!, password: password!);
if (user.user !=null) {                       // added user.user
  CustomerInfo(email: user.user!.email);     //added user.user!.email
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CustomerScreen()));
}
} catch (e) {
print(e);
}
```

Comment: That gave me an error again. I think trying to send like this is not working. @ismail

Comment: in which part are you getting the error? Is it not passing data to CustomerInfo() class at all or you are getting diff error ?

Comment: If you check the CustomerInfo class I'm printing the email data in the getCustomerData() function before everything starts. And with this solution, print returning me null value.